# Can 'too'be used immediately after the subject?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adverb-position

Let her too wake up to a hot coffee.

(or)

Let her wake up to a hot cup of coffee too.

Here I am trying to convey that what she does for you everyday, you do it for her too. 
I want to use the first sentence because the usage of 'too'after subject emphasizes more on the latter but I don't know whether it is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are grammatical. However, most style guides would recommend putting the *too* in your first sentence between a pair of commas.

For instance, *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 6.52:

> When *too* comes in the middle of the sentence or clause, however, a comma aids comprehension.
>
> She, too, decided against the early showing.

---

Following that guideline, your sentence would look like this:

> Let her, too, wake up to a hot coffee.

But that's a matter of style. It's still grammatical without the commas.